# SASS map inheritance on different values of body attribute

Tags: html, sass

I have several SASS color maps for the template:

```
$map-black: (
   $primary-color:    black,
   $secondary-color:  grey
)
$map-white: (
   $primary-color:    white,
   $secondary-color:  grey
)
```

Can I bind specific map on body attribute value or class?

```
<body data-color="white">
    <h1>Title</h1>
</body>

body[data-color="white"] {
    @use $map-white;
}
body[data-color="black"] {
    @use $map-black;
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as an `attr` attribute. I'd suggest you use a customized `data-` attribute. E.g. `data-color="white"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain HTML5: not that I know of. But you can write yourself a mixin, which produces this kind of output as simple css-classnames with a for-loop over your maps.

you can test the following on sass-meister (https://www.sassmeister.com/)

```
$map-black: (
  primary-color:    '#fff',
  secondary-color:  '#ccc'
);

$map-white: (
  primary-color:    '#fff',
  secondary-color:  '#ccc'
);

$themes: (
  white: $map-white,
  black: $map-black
);

@each $theme, $colors in $themes {
  .#{$theme} {
    background: map-get($colors, primary-color);
    color: map-get($colors, secondary-color);
  }
  h1.#{$theme} {
    color: map-get($colors, secondary-color);
  }
  .#{$theme} > p {
    color: map-get($colors, secondary-color);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of mixin?

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is a bit off. You can define two maps this way:

```
$red: (
   primary-color:    red,
   secondary-color:  orange
);
$blue: (
   primary-color:    blue,
   secondary-color:  green
);
```

Then you can access the values in the maps using `map-get($map, key)`:

```
div[data-color="red"] h1 {
  color: map-get($red, primary-color);
}
div[data-color="red"] .desc {
  color: map-get($red, secondary-color);
}
div[data-color="blue"] h1 {
  color: map-get($blue, primary-color);
}
div[data-color="blue"] .desc {
  color: map-get($blue, secondary-color);
}
```

This will apply to an HTML structure like this:

```
<div data-color="red">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p class="desc">Description</p>
</div>
<div data-color="blue">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p class="desc">Description</p>
</div>
```

You can test it [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ltor2j23/)